# Are the Beam elements created from a 3D polyline in Ansys SpaceClaim also 3D in their DOF?

Tags: ansys, ansys-workbench

I have created a 3D polyline and assigned a Beam profile to it. But I don't get the results from my Explicit analysis where this beam is in contact with a shell surface. I am afraid that the Beam has not enough DOFs as I would need.

since the Explicit solver in Ansys is AutoDyn, I can not check what element types I have. where can I check them ?

Comment: Have you checked the Ansys helpfiles?

Comment: I don't know where it might have been mentioned, if you know, please adress me

Comment: You need to read them thoroughly, I can remember how big they were 15 or 20 years ago, but you have the  advantage of online and searching - we only had a simple index...

Comment: @SolarMike It's not even in Ansys manual...

Comment: The number of DOF is in your beam element help page indeed. I'm not sure your question makes sense without anymore code or working example.